# encodeWithCoder unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nscoding

I am getting this exception but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I am writing an extension to attempt to save this struct from the NewsAPISwiftLibrary to NSUserDefaults: [NewsAPISource](https://github.com/lucaslimapoa/NewsAPISwift/blob/master/NewsAPISwift/Classes/NewsAPISource.swift)

This is the code to my extension:

```
extension NewsAPISource {

    init?(data: NSData) {
        if let coding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? Encoding {
            id = coding.id
            name = coding.name
            sourceDescription = coding.sourceDescription
            url = coding.url
            category = coding.category
            language = coding.language
            country = coding.country
            sortBysAvailable = coding.sortBysAvailable as [SortBy]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func encode() -> NSData {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: Encoding(self)) as NSData
    }

    private class Encoding: NSObject, NSCoding {

        let id: SourceId?
        let name: String?
        let sourceDescription: String?
        let url: String?
        let category: NewsAPISwift.Category?
        let language: Language?
        let country: Country?
        let sortBysAvailable: [SortBy]

        init(_ source: NewsAPISource) {
            id = source.id
            name = source.name
            sourceDescription = source.sourceDescription
            url = source.url
            category = source.category
            language = source.language
            country = source.country
            sortBysAvailable = source.sortBysAvailable
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? SourceId
            name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String
            sourceDescription = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"sourceDescription") as? String
            url = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "url") as? String
            category = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "category") as? NewsAPISwift.Category
            language = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "language") as? Language
            country = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "country") as? Country

            if let sorts = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "sortBysAvailable") as? [SortBy] {
                self.sortBysAvailable = sorts
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
            aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
            aCoder.encode(sourceDescription, forKey: "sourceDescription")
            aCoder.encode(url, forKey: "url")
            aCoder.encode(category, forKey: "category")
            aCoder.encode(language, forKey: "language")
            aCoder.encode(country, forKey: "country")
            aCoder.encode(sortBysAvailable, forKey: "sortBysAvailable")    
        }    
    }
}
```

I create a new struct like this:

```
let emptySource = NewsAPISource(id: "nil", name: "nil", sourceDescription: "nil", url: "nil", category: .business, language: .english, country: .unitedStates, sortBysAvailable: [.top])
```

and attempt to encode it like this:

```
emptySourceArray.encode()
```

This is the line that causes the exception. Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

The full error is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800005f4d0'

Comment: Does the object Country also conform to NSCoding?

Comment: @FabioBerger Country is a String enum

Comment: and what about SourceId and Language? ^^

Comment: @FabioBerger SourceID is a type-alias for a String, Language is another String enum, Category is yet another String enum, [SortBy] is an array of string enums.

Comment: @foobar5512 `String` `enum`s are still `enum`s and thus cannot conform to `NSCoding`. You will need to encode their `rawValue`, which is a `String` (bridging to `NSString`, which _does_ conform with `NSCoding`).

Comment: Have you scanned [these search results on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=_SwiftValue+encodeWithCoder%3A+unrecognized+selector)?

Comment: @ItaiFerber Got it, Thanks!